# Linear Regression Predict next minutes

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a linear model already compiled, where I pass to it 3 variables and I have one output:

Input: Temperature1, Temperature2 and Level
Output: Pressure

These data are collected every 1 minute through an equipment. In this case I can predict the next minute, being that I get the last value of each variable and subtracted by the current value and I have a difference. This difference I add with the last value collected, so I move to the model and it gives me the prediction of the variable Pressure. Ex:

Time Temperature1
10:00 100
10:01 105

In this case I know that the variation was 5, so I add 105 + 5 = 110 and step as a parameter for the model to predict my pressure.

That's what I'm talking about for the next minute.

My question is, how would I do this to predict the next 60 minutes of the Pressure, being that I do not have the next 60 minutes of the input variables (actual values).

Today I'm doing what I did for every minute and always adding the difference, always taking the last 60 minutes, is that correct?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have historical data, you can check the past prediction accuracy when projecting 60 minutes ahead. You might find that under some circumstances the 60 minute model predictions are more accurate than at others, and this information can help you tune the model - for example making two models based on regions of Temperature1 might be better than a single model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!!

I'm doing this, but I'm averaging the difference of the historical points.

Otherwise, is it possible to use GridSearch to improve the score?

Comment: I recommend visual inspection of scatterplots for T1 vs. pressure, T2 vs. pressure, and Level vs. Pressure. The purpose is to determine if there is any obvious non-linear relationship, for example you might use log(T1) if this is indicated by visual analysis of the scatterplots.